# npm says it is not valid json but jsonlint.com says it is valid

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, angularfire

So basically this is the json file for package.json which I used npm install for: (its for the angularfire-seed project on github if anyone wants to know)

```
 {
  "name": "angularfire-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for Angular + Firebase with AngularFire",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "~0.10",
    "protractor": "~0.20.1",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js  --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor-conf.js",
    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + cat('app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  }
}
```

but I keep getting an error message from NPM which says that its "failed to parse json" and that "package.json must be actual JSON, not just Javascript" (error code EJSONPARSE) but jsonlint.com says its a valid JSON format. What is going on? and what can I do to actually successfully run "npm install" from command line.

Comment: Does the file end in a `.js` or a `.json`?

Comment: it ends in .json, yeah, made sure of that and also viewed it as a file and it says package.json and is a JSON file which is confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ npm install semver
$ node
> var semver = require('semver');
> semver.valid("~0.10"); // returns null
null
```

According to this: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json, all your version numbers should comply with node-semver.

Git allows to digit version no. whereas npm doesn't.
So in your case, 
the dependency version numbers needs to be in the format `major.minor.patch` in package.json.

Comment: So, there's both a configuration mistake (wrong version number) and a bug on NPM (says that problem is on the JSON format, when the error is actually something else).

Comment: Yeah, you have multiple wrong version numbers. Tell me if it works now ?

Comment: I dont think its a npm bug actually, the error message i get from npm tells me that its the author's problem with the package.json, I believe actually its the package.json from the node modules I'm downloading thats actually conflicting and causing a problem

Comment: yup, as @mthpvg said the version should be specified as per semver standard i.e. `major.minor.patch`